# Swift: arrays in image name

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimage

I have a batch of images with names like pattern35 and pattern7. My UIImage changes and it needs to be a random image. There are 84 patterns. I have an array of random numbers. I tried this, but I get the error 'array' is an unresolved identifier.

```
patternRoom.image = UIImage(named: "pattern\(array[0])")
```

Comment: Where do you have your array of random numbers declared compared to the location of the line you posted?

Comment: @PhillipMills In a separate func but in the same class

Comment: Defined _in_ the function, as in `func f() { let array = [1,2,3] }`?  In which case that's the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have a scope problem with your array being defined in a function that is not the one where it's used.  Consider the following code as an example of a declaration that's available to other functions:

```
class SampleClass {
    let array: [Int] = [1, 2, 3]

    func showThem() {
        for index in 0...2 {
            println("Value is \(array[index])")
        }
    }
}

let sc: SampleClass = SampleClass()
sc.showThem()
```

(Playgrounds are great for trying out this kind of thing in isolation from "production" code that may be more complicated.)

Answer (score 1):

**You can do like this:**

```
patternRoom.image = UIImage(named: "pattern\(arc4random_uniform(84))")
```